# Reverse Sorting Reducer Keys

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

What is the best approach to get the Map Output keys to a reducer in reverse order? By default the reducer receives all keys in ascending order of keys. Any help or comments widely appreciated.

In simple words, in the normal scenario, if a map emits keys *1,4,3,5,2* the reducer receives the same as *1,2,3,4,5*. I would like the reducer to receive *5,4,3,2,1* instead.

Comment: make the key an object of a class which implements the Comparable interface and override the compare method to your liking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Hadoop 1.X, you can specify a custom comparator class for your outputs using [`JobConf.setOutputKeyComparatorClass`](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r1.0.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.html#setOutputKeyComparatorClass%28java.lang.Class%29).

Your comparator must implement the [`RawComparator` interface](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r1.0.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/RawComparator.html).

With Hadoop 2.X, this is done by using [`Job.setSortComparatorClass`](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html#setSortComparatorClass%28java.lang.Class%29), still with an implementation of `RawComparator`.

Answer (score 5):

Sample, simple  code

```
class MyKeyComparator extends WritableComparator {
    protected DescendingKeyComparator() {
        super(Text.class, true);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public int compare(WritableComparable w1, WritableComparable w2) {
        Text key1 = (Text) w1;
        Text key2 = (Text) w2;          
        return -1 * key1.compareTo(key2);
    }
}
```

Then add it it to the job

```
job.setSortComparatorClass(MyKeyComparator.class);
```

you can change the below text type as per ur use.

```
Text key1 = (Text) w1;
Text key2 = (Text) w2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply your key by -1 before emitting it from your mapper. This will cause the framework to sort it in ascending order but negative values -5,-4,-3,-2,-1   and then in the reducer multiply it again by -1 resulting in 5,4,3,2,1. This will cause the framework to sort in sudo-descending order. In a more complex sort it is best to write a custom class for comparing and then set it in your driver class.

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer from @user3123372 you could extend the Text Class and override the compare method.

```
public class NewText extends Text implements Writable,WritableComparable<BinaryComparable> { 
 @Override
 public int compareTo(BinaryComparable other) {
   return -1 * super.compareTo(other);  //Return inverse value
  }
}
```