# reverse MapReduce order

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, comparator

if for a simple mapreduce job , say wordcount. The output comes out sorted, is there any way that the order will come out in reverse, (words starting with Z coming first) or any other customized order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse Sorting Reducer Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670953/reverse-sorting-reducer-keys)

Answer (score 4):

Look Koushik,
You can do this very well but you need to customise. In order to customise the Key you need to implement WritableComparable or extend the WritableComparator class in order to implement the methods compareTo() or compare() respectively. Each method has its own pros and cons and that beyond the scop of you question so I am not going into that. 
Coming to your question.
Keeping in mind efficency considerations in Serialisation/Desirialization that tends to cause a network overhead, I will implement the compare() method which will explicitly sort the output key values in descending order. Following is the method definition that you may wish tto go through

```
public static class DescendingKey extends WritableComparator {
    protected DescendingKey() {
        super(Text.class, true);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public int compare(WritableComparable w1, WritableComparable w2) {
        LongWritable key1 = (LongWritable) w1;
        LongWritable key2 = (LongWritable) w2;          
        return -1 * key1.compareTo(key2);
    }
}
```

here take a look at the following 'return' statement
 `return -1 * key1.compareTo(key2);`
The **-1** is the only token or say operand that actually is instrumental in getting the keys sorted into descending order. If you change -1 to +1 the reverse seems to happen i.e. the whole data gets sorted in ascneding order. Get back to me in case you feel the answer doubtful.
Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks a lot  :)
I will come back after implementing it .

Comment: If you don't get the output as desired, please send the code to me by editing your question and attaching the code

Comment: sure!
I have accepted the answer but it will not make any difference, because I dont have 15 reputation yet to make it public, If you wish you can accept my question,that way I will get 5 reputation ....

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the Text Class and override the compare method.

```
public class NewText extends Text implements Writable,WritableComparable<BinaryComparable> { 
 @Override
 public int compareTo(BinaryComparable other) {
   return -1 * super.compareTo(other);  //Return inverse value
  }
}
```